# Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library together with xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-storage

Is it possible to use Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library together with xamarinforms. I have tried to add the nuget to XF project running netstandard2.0, but get a linking error on iOS. Now I wonder if it is possible to run this nuget in XamarinForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that it's not by design supported currently, and it could be a good item to evaluate. Would you open an issue [here](https://github.com/azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/) as well, and let's see if there are more person loving this idea.